# Android Imagebutton is clipped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

I'm having issues with my Activity and an ImageButton inside it. It looks like it is clipping:

[image]

This is the XML of the corresponding activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/todo_linear_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/todo_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Additionally the Layout Designer in Android Studio shows the Layout correctly:

[image]

Where is the problem here? I already tried to change margin or padding values but the Button is still clipping in the running app on my android device.

Comment: You are using vector right for image inside ImageButton?

Comment: It works fine when i try it. Have you tried setting the srcCompat to something other than ic_input_add? It is really weird because this icon was present since the earliest android version

Comment: @nupadhyaya yes I did. I tried using another plus Symbol for example (I dont know the exact name atm)

Comment: @NKnuelle try by giving height to linear layout or use android:src instead of app:srcCompat

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what's happening is that the device you're running your app on doesn't have the `@android:drawable/ic_input_add` drawable.

I tried running the code you posted, and everything worked for me. However, if I delete the `app:srcCompat` attribute from the `<ImageButton>` tag, then I get the same behavior you posted in your first screenshot.

In general, you can't rely on 100% of devices having `@android:` resources. Some manufacturers remove resources, and others replace the values with nonsense (I've seen `@android:color/white` come through as gray, for example).

I recommend creating your own drawable (maybe even just manually copying the one from Android and adding it to your project), and referencing that instead.

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_own_add"
```

Comment: This seems to be the issue. I'll give it a try tomorrow. I never thought, that android ressources could not be present on an Android device. It actually sounds strange 

Answer (score 0):

Changing the app:srcCompat to:
    `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"` did it! So the issue was, that the device didn't find that icon and displayed just something gray.